# Is it better to learn android app development from drag and drop features of android studio without properly knowing xml?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Question as an absolute beginner. I just completed the core java and started learning android. I have searched a lot for good courses of an android and I found one from google on Udacity. That is awesome. But the problem is that that course is from 2015. So, it is outdated now. They taught xml by code not by drag and drop of android. That's why some code is not working now!
I know these drag and drop features of android studio is to help us and save our time. But as a beginner if I don't know the proper use of xml, then how I will become a good android app dev?

Comment: Your question does not suit the rules of the site and it's going to be closed. You should check [ask]

Comment: Please look at this

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner, we tend to worry too much about things and whether or not this or that will be good or not but I can assure you that in the end one way or the other you will eventually get a hang of it. From personal experience, working with both XML and the drag and drop has no issue whatsoever but its good to understand the XML part as you cant always rely on the drag and drop feature. The only catch is to get your hands dirty with creating projects and using the built in features of Android Studio such as code completion and as good starting place I'd recommend watching YouTube tutorials and following the likes of  [CodingInFlow](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_Fh8kvtkVPkeihBs42jGcA) who are great teachers in Android. Good Luck in Your Future Projects

Comment: Please do not try to answer [Off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions this will encourage people to ask more Off-topics

Comment: @ADM duly noted!

Comment: @mateendev anytime but seems the rules dont agree with the question. all the best though

Comment: @Mosericko yes bro. I don't know why. It's my first time to posted a question

Comment: @mateendev its opinion based: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions